# Extending generic props in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Sorry if the heading is misleading. I can't seem to find a suitable title.
I have a two classes.

```
****************Form.tsx

interface Props{}
interface State{}
class Form extends Component<Props, State>{
   protected submit(){
      // contains a code when form submits
   }
}



****************Login.tsx

class LoginForm extends Form{
   render(){
       return(
          <View>
            <Button onClick = {() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
            <Button onClick= {() => this.submit()} />
          </View>

       );
   }
}
```

I wanna do this

```
<LoginForm navigation = {someObject} />
```

But I cannot do this because i cant seem to find a workaround. I just wanna know how to pass more props to LoginForm.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it will only work if form is always extended and not used as a component. In my example I never intended to use form as a Component. so here is a solution if it helps.

```
***********Form.tsx
interface State{}
class Form<P= {}> extends Component<P, State>{

}

***********Login.tsx
interface LoginFormProps{
   navigation: SomeObjectType
}

class Login extends Form<LoginFormProps>{
}
```

and then i can do

```
<LoginForm navigation = {someObject} />
```